# symfony phpunit tokenstorage

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Hi I need to test a functionnality with phpunit, I need a complete authentication like a human.

I have tried to create a client and go to the login page, fill the form, and valid the form. But my client does'nt have tokenstorage (null value). I have tried [this tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/testing/http_authentication.html#creating-the-authentication-token) But when I get I get the user of the tokenstorage (getUser()) I have a string not a User object :(

There is a good method to do what I want ?

Comment: I think you should show some code and context around it to be able to answer at any detailed level. In general, when testing some secured functionality, you don't "go to login page and fill anything". Instead of that, you want to create (in the test) a security token, put it in session and make a request to secured area (that's exactly what the article you've referenced is about). Which token to create and how to put it in session depends on your security config and general auth workflow of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to test the loginform you can directly use a user that is logged in:

Update the setUp method and use $this->user in your Test. For this to work you need to have fixtures which create a user and use the username and password of that user. [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html#using-a-faster-authentication-mechanism-only-for-tests)

```
$this->user = static::createClient([], [
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'username',
    'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'password',
]);
```